# Multi input generator with keras tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, generator

I am new with tensorflow, as well as in deep learning.
I need a clarification about what is a generator, and tips to create one with 2 inputs.

From my reading, we use a generator with the method model.fit_generator(generator, ...). With the new verison of tensorflow, the method model.fit(x=generator, ...) is accepted. This means that now, we use the method model.fit(...).
I have a lot of data. Actually, I have 2 different inputs, and both are images. Without using a generator, I am able to use model.fit(...) with 2 inputs, like that:

```
self.model.fit( x= [input1, input2],
                validation_data = ([x_val_doppler, x_val_bmode], y_val),
                epochs = nb_epochs ,
                batch_size = batch_size,
                callbacks=self._make_train_valid_callbacks(
                nb_epochs=nb_epochs,
                save_folder_path=save_folder_path,
                weights_filename=weights_filename,
                train_monitor=train_monitor
            )
```

My GPU does not have enough memory, and I need to use a generator to avoid this issue. I do not really understand how a generator works. From my understanding, the generator is running in parallel of the GPU, and creates data augmentation. What does it mean ?

Moreover, I already have a generator, but this one takes in argument only one input.
My idea was to create two independent generators, and then use model.fit(...):

```
training_gen1 = DatasetGenerator(x_train_input1, y_train)
training_gen2 = DatasetGenerator(x_train_input2, y_train)
validation_gen1 = DatasetGenerator(x_validation_input1, y_val)
validation_gen2 = DatasetGenerator(x_validation_input2, y_valid)

self.model.fit( x= [training_gen1, training_gen2],
                validation_data = [validation_gen1, validation_gen2],
                epochs = nb_epochs ,
                batch_size = batch_size,
                callbacks=self._make_train_valid_callbacks(
                nb_epochs=nb_epochs,
                save_folder_path=save_folder_path,
                weights_filename=weights_filename,
                train_monitor=train_monitor
              )
```

Note that input1 and input2 have the same label.
I searched on the net different solutiopn to create a multi input generator, but I have not found anything conclusive, probably because I did not understand in depth how a generator works.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You would not need to create your own generator for image dataset. Keras already has ```tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory()``` for this. Also I do not understand how a generator will solve your problem? Perhaps what you are looking for is sending the data in batches instead.

Comment: Hi yuRa, 
Thanks for answer.

Actually, I have too much data. The RAM of my GPU is not big enough to store all of them. This mean that yes, you are right, I am trying to send data in batches. But I red than fit() sent all the data in the RAM of the GPU, while fit_generator() sent the data in through batches, and data are from generator. And my problem is to create a multi input generator, as my network has two different inputs and one label.